# What deals did Pakistan broker for the Taliban-led Afghanistan as a mediator?

Tags: geopolitics, pakistan, afghanistan

> The relationship with the Taliban-led government in Afghanistan is
> crucial. Pakistan’s role as a mediator and its policies towards the
> Afghan Taliban will affect peace and stability in the region. A
> government in Islamabad looking to foster stability in Afghanistan
> could work towards ensuring that Afghan soil is not used for
> anti-Pakistan activities.
>
> Relations between Pakistan and Afghanistan have become increasingly
> worrying due to security concerns. Pakistan has accused the
> Taliban-led government in Afghanistan of not doing enough to prevent
> attacks from armed groups, including the Islamic State in Khorasan
> Province (ISKP or ISIS-K) and the Tehreek-e-Taliban Pakistan (TTP),
> across the porous border between the two countries. A notable incident
> was a suicide bombing in Bajaur district in July 2023, which killed
> more than 54 people and was claimed by ISKP. Pakistan has expressed
> frustration over what it perceives as the Afghan Taliban’s lack of
> decisive action against these groups, leading to a deteriorating
> security situation in regions like Khyber Pakhtunkhwa.

https://www.geopoliticalmonitor.com/the-geopolitical-impact-of-pakistans-elections/

What deals did Pakistan broker for the Taliban-led Afghanistan as a mediator? Being a mediator involves facilitating negotiations and helping parties in a dispute reach a mutually acceptable agreement. The mediator works as a neutral third party, assisting in communication, understanding each party's concerns, and guiding the process toward a resolution. The mediator may propose solutions, encourage compromises, and foster a cooperative atmosphere. The article claims that Pakistan plays the role of a mediator for the Afghan government, but didn't say what deals, negotiations it brokered.

Comment: TBH that source may be just throwing words around without much consideration. I suppose Pakistan (under Khan) may have helped a bit e.g. with smoothing the Chinese visits to Afg, establishing "unofficial" relations etc. But you'd be hard pressed  to find much public detail about that. More like "fixer" than "mediator" IMO.

Comment: If anything, there are a lot of stories about the (Afghan) Talibans mediating between Pakistan and the TTP (Pakistani Taliban).

Comment: And Pakistan offered to mediate between the Taliban and the US, but were rebuffed by the latter https://www.dawn.com/news/1716452